# визуальный редактор в SQLite android

Tags: sqlite, sql

Здравствуйте, можно ли редактировать или же добавить данные в БД (SQLite в Android) в визуальном виде, как на MySql (PhpMyAdmin), например у тебя есть 4 полей в БД, и для заполнения есть 4 полей в программе, вводишь туда данные и нажимаешь на add или же ok и тут в базу добавляется данные введенные тобою?

Comment: Из телефона или PC?

Comment: PC (Windows OS)

Comment: Погугли [SQLite database browser](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=sqlite+database+browser) там их полно. Yawns...

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с базой в Windows:

1. [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)
2. [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Для работы с базой в Android:

1. [SQLite Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&hl=ru)
2. [SQLite Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kokufu.android.apps.sqliteviewer.free&hl=ru)

Для работы с базой в Linux:

1. [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)
2. [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

**P.S:** Лично я использую [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/). Все есть, удобно. Нареканий нет